# Detect texture orientation in the image

Tags: image, imagemagick, textures, orientation, detect

I have thousands of images, those are classified into two categories, the first is before flow field establish, the second is after 
flow field establish，my task is find the image which the flow field just started.

Currently, I get the edge of these images use MagickImage, and I think if the texture in the image is almost horizontally, then this image is which I want

[image: I want]

but how can I detect the orientation of the image? Anyone can help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: Could you please try and improve your explanation - it is hard to understand as there is no indication how your description relates to any of the images. Which images do you want to detect? What characterises the ones you want to detect? Why are two images marked red? Which images are before flow? Which ones are after flow? Which ones are just at flow?

Comment: the first four is the original images,the after four is the edge of the first four which i use MagickImage's API:Edge get it,1 and 2 are the images before flow field establish, 3 is flow field just started, and 4 is the image after flow field establish, the red one is the image which I want to detect out. Because I don't know how to detect it out so I Edged the iamges, I think maybe I can get some clues from the edge. like the image7 ,when the flow just started the edge starting to change to horizontally, and What puzzles me is how program know the edge become change to horizontally

Comment: Is the flow always horizontal?

Comment: yes，the flow always horizontal